# Can a 290mm x 45mm lvl beam be used as a structural ridge beam?

Tags: roof, framing, structural, beam

Also are ridge beams only used for exposed ceilings, or can you install ceiling joists which are connected to the rafters, - i assume this would provide extra support.

This is for a single story house and the ridge beam would fall in the middle of a width of 8.2m, the length of this portion of the house is also 8.2m.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on if you're building a dog house, shed, home or villa.

You are asking for specific answers about an obscure subject.  Gather your information about the project and speak with a Qualified and Licensed Engineer in the jurisdiction that you will be doing the work.